# How to get the count of unread missed call whose instance has removed from notification

Tags: android

I require to get the count of missedcalls that are still in notification and count of unread missed calls that I have not interacted; but just removed from notification. I have used the following query. But both returns the same result while missed call in notification and that removed from notification too.

```
String newWhere = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" +
CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";

String[] newProjection = {CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE};

Cursor newCursor =
this.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
newProjection, newWhere, null, null);

mNewMissedCallCount = newCursor.getCount();

newCursor.close();

String unreadWhere = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" +   CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE    + " AND " +    CallLog.Calls.IS_READ + "=0"; 

String[] unreadProjection =  {CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,   CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE};

Cursor unreadCursor = this.getContentResolver()query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
unreadProjection, unreadWhere, null, null); 

mUnreadMissedCallCount = unreadCursor.getCount();

unreadCursor.close();
```

Please suggest me
How to get the count of unread missed call that has removed from notification

Answer (score 0):

You need to only check the ***unread*** message condition,

that is,

```
 String where = CallLog.Calls.IS_READ+"=0";
```